# Using Geopandas and Shapely to merge polygons (but not always intersecting) within a single geometry column

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have the following structure (this isn't the exact data but a reflection of it form) of data where `Lat, Long` is the location of the farm; and the distribution area is the GeoPandas `geometry` column/info:

| Farm type | Lat | Long | Avg yield | Max yeild | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | x1 | y1 | 50 | 100 | POLYGON (a) |
| Apples | x1 | y1 | 50 | 100 | POLYGON (b) |
| Apples | x1 | y1 | 50 | 100 | POLYGON (c) |
| Bananas | x2 | y2 | 100 | 150 | POLYGON (d) |
| Bananas | x2 | y2 | 100 | 150 | POLYGON (e) |
| Bananas | x2 | y2 | 100 | 150 | POLYGON (f) |
| Oranges | x3 | y3 | 70 | 100 | POLYGON (g) |
| Oranges | x3 | y3 | 70 | 100 | POLYGON (h) |
| Oranges | x3 | y3 | 70 | 100 | POLYGON (i) |

As you can see the descriptive information is the same for each instance of `Apples`, `Bananas` and `Oranges` EXCEPT for the Polygon value in `'geometry'`.

What I would like to do is merge each of the rows based on `Farm Type` so my DataFrame looks like:

| Farm type | Lat | Long | Avg yield | Max yeild | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | x1 | y1 | 50 | 100 | MULTIPOLYGON (a,b,c) |
| Bananas | x2 | y2 | 100 | 150 | MULTIPOLYGON (d,e,f) |
| Oranges | x3 | y3 | 70 | 100 | MULTIPOLYGON (g,h,i) |

Since the polygons describe the distribution area, the polygons don't always intersect so we can't assume intersection i.e. distribution area could cross over to an island; which is a separate polygon, etc.

Some code I have is:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import unary_union

for i in df['Farm type'].unique():
    temp_poly = df.loc[df['Farm type']==i]
    df.loc[df['Farm type']==i, 'geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries(unary_union(temp_poly['geometry']))
```

But it doesn't seem to be doing what I want, I think I might be slicing the data frame with `.loc[]` incorrectly?
I am happy to provide further information upon request, but I can't share my actual data/code which is why I made a toy scenario.

Comment: Generally, a “toy” example is preferred, but it should still work. For example, you could create extremely simple polygons. See the guide to creating a [mre] and  this blog post on [crafting a minimal bug report](//matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.dissolve`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.dissolve.html), i.e.:

```py
df.dissolve("Farm type")
```

See the [user guide](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/aggregation_with_dissolve.html) for more info.

Comment: Ahahahahahaaa. This was EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you so much! I knew it would be simple, but I didn't expect it to be THAT simple. Wow.